# Custom parameter not updating in JW Player

Tags: c#, .net, api, updates, jwplayer

I am using JW player APIs to update video metadata in JW player using web application developed in .net.
From my web application, I am sending video name, description, tags and custom parameter as video metadata. Everything works fine when I update a video without giving custom parameter. The video name, tags, description are updated successfully. However, when I provide custom parameter , nothing is updated.

I am using following urls.

**With custom parameter** // Does not work
https://api.jwplatform.com/videos/update/?api_format=json&api_nonce=80684843&api_timestamp=1543216871&api_signature=5274e2ba5ba2cc64eb532ef2ff807144bb6c9aac&api_key=ezMb5C69&video_key=VUBYzLng&title=TestVideoName&tags=TestTag&description=TestDesc&custom.FileName=test.mp4

this gives following response-

> {"status": "error", "message":
>   "api_signature: Signature is invalid. Received signature:
>   5274e2ba5ba2cc64eb532ef2ff807144bb6c9aac. Server assembled SBS:
>   api_format=json&api_key=ezMb5C69&api_nonce=80684843&api_timestamp=1543216871&custom.FileName=test.mp4&description=TestDesc&tags=TestTag&title=TestVideoName&video_key=VUBYzLng",
>   "code": "SignatureInvalid", "title": "Signature Invalid"}

*[Please note in the url, custome parameter is provided at the end]*

When I do not give custom parameter, it successfully updates the video metadata

**Without custom parameter** // it works
https://api.jwplatform.com/videos/update/?api_format=json&api_nonce=80684843&api_timestamp=1543216871&api_signature=5274e2ba5ba2cc64eb532ef2ff807144bb6c9aac&api_key=ezMb5C69&video_key=VUBYzLng&title=TestVideoName&tags=TestTag&description=TestDesc

Can someone let me know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you getting a fresh signature each time you make an API call? Also, is FileName a reserved name?

Comment: @tshimkus yes I am getting new signature for each API call and FileName is not the reserved keyword